# How to use environment variables in React with vite?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, environment-variables, vite

I was trying to access environment variables, at first, I got an error saying `process is not defined`.

Then I tried this but I'm not sure why it's not working

**.env**

```
VITE_BASE_URL="https://jikan1.p.rapidapi.com/"
VITE_HOST="jikan1.p.rapidapi.com"
VITE_KEY="abcdefghij12345678"
```

**Page.jsx**

```
let api = {
  base: import.meta.env.VITE_BASE_URL,
  host: import.meta.env.VITE_HOST,
  key: import.meta.env.VITE_KEY
};

function Upcoming() {
      

    console.log(api);
    return (
      <div>
      <p>{api.host}</p>
      <p>{api.base}</p>
      <p>{api.key}</p>
    </div>
)
}
```

I only get api.host but the base and key are undefined

can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: I've removed the [tag:vue] since it's kinda unrelated here.

Comment: @kissu  I thought it might be, since I used to use env variables without vite but no problem

Comment: Vue is a framework. Vite is a build tool like Webpack, it's unrelated to the Vue ecosystem now.

Comment: @kissu i get it now thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I figured out why it's not working, silly mistake.

it's just because I didn't restart the server
there is nothing wrong other than that.

if you don't stop the server and start it again,`env` file won't be updated.